# Calculate Working Days without Holidays for specific Country

Tags: c#

I've been googling around here to find a solution for my problem, but did not found any so far.
Well, I found some parcial functions that could work, but as I am newbie in C#, I need some help merging all code to work.
So, I need to calculate Working Days between 2 dates, ignoring weekends and Portuguese Holidays.
For the holidays, I have this code which returns all Portuguese Holidays:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetHolidays(int year)
    {
        List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 1, 1)); //New Year Day
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 4, 25)); //Dia da Liberdade (PT)
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 5, 1)); //Labour Day
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 6, 10)); //Dia de Portugal (PT)
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 8, 15)); //Assumption of Mary
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 10, 5)); //Implantação da república (PT)
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 11, 1)); //All Saints' Day
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 1)); //Restauração da independência (PT)
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 8)); //Imaculada Conceição (PT?)
        result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 25)); //Christmas
        foreach (DateTime holiday in variable)
        {
            if (!result.Contains(holiday)) //if the holiday already exists then don't add
            {
                result.Add(holiday);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And my function to calculate Working days is this one I found here in StackOverFlow:

```
public static int BusinessDaysUntil(this DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay, params DateTime[] bankHolidays)
    {
        firstDay = firstDay.Date;
        lastDay = lastDay.Date;
        if (firstDay > lastDay)
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect last day " + lastDay);

        TimeSpan span = lastDay - firstDay;
        int businessDays = span.Days + 1;
        int fullWeekCount = businessDays / 7;
        // find out if there are weekends during the time exceedng the full weeks
        if (businessDays > fullWeekCount * 7)
        {
            // we are here to find out if there is a 1-day or 2-days weekend
            // in the time interval remaining after subtracting the complete weeks
            int firstDayOfWeek = (int)firstDay.DayOfWeek;
            int lastDayOfWeek = (int)lastDay.DayOfWeek;
            if (lastDayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek)
                lastDayOfWeek += 7;
            if (firstDayOfWeek <= 6)
            {
                if (lastDayOfWeek >= 7)// Both Saturday and Sunday are in the remaining time interval
                    businessDays -= 2;
                else if (lastDayOfWeek >= 6)// Only Saturday is in the remaining time interval
                    businessDays -= 1;
            }
            else if (firstDayOfWeek <= 7 && lastDayOfWeek >= 7)// Only Sunday is in the remaining time interval
                businessDays -= 1;
        }

        // subtract the weekends during the full weeks in the interval
        businessDays -= fullWeekCount + fullWeekCount;

        // subtract the number of bank holidays during the time interval
        foreach (DateTime bankHoliday in bankHolidays)
        {
            DateTime bh = bankHoliday.Date;
            if (firstDay <= bh && bh <= lastDay)
                --businessDays;
        }

        return businessDays;
    }
```

But, this code uses the DateTime[] bankHolidays and I need to change it to take my holidays into account (GetHolidays()).
Can you please help me changing the code?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question, this is an assignment... Try something yourself please and when you stumble upon a specific problem you can ask a question.

Comment: It seems that the answer to your question is simple: replace `foreach(DateTime bankHoliday in bankHolidays)` with `foreach (DateTime bankHoliday in GetHolidays(2016))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's a date (e.g. 1st of May) that matter, not year, which we ignore (set to `1`):

```
private static List<DateTime> PortugueseHolidays = new List<DateTime>() {
  new DateTime(1, 1, 1)), //New Year Day
  new DateTime(1, 4, 25), //Dia da Liberdade (PT)
  new DateTime(1, 5, 1), //Labour Day
  new DateTime(1, 6, 10), //Dia de Portugal (PT)
  new DateTime(1, 8, 15), //Assumption of Mary
  new DateTime(1, 10, 5), //Implantação da república (PT)
  new DateTime(1, 11, 1), //All Saints' Day
  new DateTime(1, 12, 1), //Restauração da independência (PT)
  new DateTime(1, 12, 8), //Imaculada Conceição (PT?)
  new DateTime(1, 12, 25), //Christmas
};
```

Test for a single date

```
private static Boolean IsHoliday(DateTime value, IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays = null) {
  if (null == holidays)
    holidays = PortugueseHolidays;

  return (value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) ||
         (value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
          holidays.Any(holiday => holiday.Day == value.Day && 
                                  holiday.Month == value.Month);
}
```

And for the range (`fromDate` *included*, `toDate` *excluded*)

```
public static int BusinessDaysUntil(this DateTime fromDate, 
                                    DateTime toDate,
                                    IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays = null) {
  int result = 0;

  for (DateTime date = fromDate.Date; date < toDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
    if (!IsHoliday(date, holidays))
      result += 1;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Unlike the OP code, yours will return correct answers if the starting day is in December and the final day is in January of the next year.  Note that "weekend" means different things in different countries.  For example, in Muslim countries a Friday-Saturday weekend is common.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Muslim_countries

Comment: @jgfооt: I see, in some contries there're other difficulties: holiday shifts (if, say, May 1st is Sunday, then May 2nd is holiday as well) and day of week based holidays, e.g. 4th Tuesday of November. Thahk goodness, Portuguese version is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks so much... Easy stuff for many but huge stuff for many (me included)

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is converting your `List` to an `Array`. Change your `GetHolidays` function to this:

```
public static DateTime[] GetHolidays(int year)
{
    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 1, 1)); //New Year Day
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 4, 25)); //Dia da Liberdade (PT)
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 5, 1)); //Labour Day
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 6, 10)); //Dia de Portugal (PT)
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 8, 15)); //Assumption of Mary
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 10, 5)); //Implantação da república (PT)
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 11, 1)); //All Saints' Day
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 1)); //Restauração da independência (PT)
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 8)); //Imaculada Conceição (PT?)
    result.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 25)); //Christmas
    foreach (DateTime holiday in variable)
    {
        if (!result.Contains(holiday)) //if the holiday already exists then don't add
        {
            result.Add(holiday);
        }
    }
    return result.ToArray<DateTime>();
}
```

Call the `BusinessDaysUntil` function using `GetHolidays()` as last parameter.